# bind xml and class which dosnt match using jaxb

Tags: java, jaxb

I am trying to Unmarshal an xml which is as given below.

```
<findCustomerProfileRequest>
    <customer>
        <mobileNumber>9999999911</mobileNumber>
    </customer>
    <dataRecord>
        <totalRecords>10</totalRecords>
        <pagingSize>10</pagingSize>
        <offsetValue>0</offsetValue>
    </dataRecord>
</findCustomerProfileRequest>
```

And i have a class file

I want to bind this to class

```
public class Customer {
    private String mobileNo;
    private String totalRecords;
    private String pagingSize;
    private String offsetValue;
    ....
      getters and setters
    ....
}
```

How can i do this. I am new to JAXB. Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE

After Annotation

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "customer")
///@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {

    @XmlElement(name = "mobileNumber", required = true)
    private String mobileNumber;
    private String totalRecords;
    private String pagingSize;
    private String offsetValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about having a proper XSD and then generate classes for the actual XML. Once generated, you can then simply copy the properties of generated class into your specific class.

Comment: the xml is a third party xml and this is just one of them. and yes they didnt provided xsd for them.

Comment: Why don't you generate your own xsd if you have xml? once you have xsd, can generate the code by yourself. In case you also use maven, there is a handy plugin to do so

Answer (score 0):

You have to annotate your Customer class with JAXB annotations

e.g.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Customer")
public class Customer {
    @XmlElement(name = "mobileNo", required = true)
    private String mobileNo;
    ....
}
```

As @Puneetsri said you can generate those annotated classes using eclipse if you have a xsd file. If you do not have it you can create that XSD file from a XML file, there are many online XSD generators that you can use.

How to bind them depends on the purpose ... if you are using webservices, or restful services then JAX-RS and JAX-WS can bind it automatically.

If you are doing an "ad-hoc" unmarshal you can pass the xml as string to the unmarshaller like e.g.

```
JAXB.unmarshal(String xml, Class<T> type)
```

Comment: giving an error `com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions`.

Comment: can you paste your annotated class? ... it seems like there is some error in the use of the annotations.

Comment: Seen your update with the annotated class i confirm that the annontation is not correct. I strongly suggest you to get the XSD file and generate the JAXB entity automatically (e.g. from eclipse). You can get a XSD file from your XML file using an online XSD generator (or any other mean) ... here is one possible solution: http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html